# @State var doesn't change, How do I check if two Arrays contain the same value?

Tags: ios, arrays, swiftui

I tried to make a color game, in which 6 Colors appear in a random order and you have to memorise them. To score, you need to tap the right Colors on the bottom in the right order. The problem is, that when it comes down to checking if the buttons were pressed in the right order, it does not work. Can anybody help me out?

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Color Game Demo
//
//  Created by Jeff Reinicke on 18.05.20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Jeff Reinicke. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    private var colors = [Color.green, Color.red, Color.blue, Color.pink, Color.orange, Color.purple]
    @State private var currentColor = Color.gray
    @State private var colorValue = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    @State private var input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    @State private var count = 0
    @State private var count2 = 0
    @State private var score = 0

    func generateRandomColor() -> Color{
        return colors.randomElement()!
    }


    var body: some View {
        VStack{

            Spacer()
            //Color Guideline
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(currentColor)
            Spacer()

            HStack{
                //start button
                Button(action: {
                    for i in 0...5{
                        self.colorValue[i] = Int.random(in: 0...5)
                    }
                    if self.count == 6{
                        self.count = 0
                    }
                    var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { t in
                        self.currentColor = self.colors[self.colorValue[self.count]]
                        self.count += 1
                        if self.count == 6{
                            t.invalidate()
                        }
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Start")
                }
                Text(String(count))
                Text(String(score))

            }
            Spacer()

            //Colorbuttons
            HStack{
                Button(action: {
                    //Check if color of button is in right order with color appeared on guideline
                    if self.colorValue[self.count2] == self.input[self.count2]{
                        self.count2 += 1
                    }
                    else{
                        self.score = 0
                        self.count2 = 0
                    }
                }) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                }
                Button(action: {
                    if self.colorValue[self.count2] == self.input[self.count2]{
                        self.score += 1
                        self.count2 += 1
                    }
                    else{
                        self.score = 0
                        self.count2 = 0
                    }
                }) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                }
                Button(action: {
                    if self.colorValue[self.count2] == self.input[self.count2]{
                        self.score += 1
                        self.count2 += 1
                    }
                    else{
                        self.score = 0
                        self.count2 = 0
                    }
                }) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                }
            }
            HStack{
                Button(action: {
                    if self.colorValue[self.count2] == self.input[self.count2]{
                        self.score += 1
                        self.count2 += 1
                    }
                    else{
                        self.score = 0
                        self.count2 = 0
                    }
                }) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.pink)
                }
                Button(action: {
                    if self.colorValue[self.count2] == self.input[self.count2]{
                        self.score += 1
                        self.count2 += 1
                    }
                    else{
                        self.score = 0
                        self.count2 = 0
                    }
                }) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                }
                Button(action: {
                    if self.colorValue[self.count2] == self.input[self.count2]{
                        self.score += 1
                        self.count2 += 1
                    }
                    else{
                        self.score = 0
                        self.count2 = 0
                    }
                }) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.purple)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually expectation is not clear, would you elaborate more on that?

Comment: At the top of the screen there is a rectangle, which if the button underneath is pressed, displays 6 Colors all random generated in a specific order. I tried to save this order in the array "colorValue". The goal is to press the colorbuttons at the bottom of the app in the exact order, the rectangle at the top displayed them. So I tried to check, when the button is pressed, if input[count2] in which count2 should represent the order the Colors appeared in, equals the colorbutton's color value. But when the colorbutton is being pressed, the score does not change, even if pressed in right order.